# How to run Eclipse with Docker on Windows using Boot2Docker?

Tags: eclipse, windows, docker, boot2docker

i installed [Boot2Docker](http://boot2docker.io/) v1.7.1 for Windows and started it like described in the manual. After that i run the docker image batmat/docker-eclipse.

Unfortunately i got the error:

> Eclipse: Cannot open display: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2elogback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.
>   Eclipse: Cannot open display:
>   Eclipse:
>   An error has occured. See the log file 
>   /home/developer/eclipse/configuration/1438451934632.log

Anyone know how to run Eclipse with Docker on Windows using Boot2Docker?

Comment: Have a look at the log it's pointing you too.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace you're seeing is not related to Docker, but to the Maven integration. Try with a clean Eclipse installation and a fresh workspace.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run x11 server on windows.
Or you build you own docker based on existing eclipse one, and install vnc server inside.